# SQL Inner Join fetch different results every time

Tags: php, mysql

my project stack in this issue bellow ,

i have 2 tables **quiziz**(filled by teacher) have 10 cols

**id,dept,subject,question,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,correct_ans,techername**

and **students** have 7 cols

**id,username,password,usertype,dept,subject,answers**

if the user logged in (successfully) in **dborad.php** he will see links every link will take him to different quiz in **quiz.php** page (**using get method to get subject and dept for student**) , in this **quiz.php** page he will see his quiz with 4 answers, my problem is the inner join not working , it suppose to fetch quiz for specific subject that he choose from **dborad.php** with some questions that is different from other students , but its not

**dboard.php**

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
if ($_SESSION['usertype'] === "isstudent") {
$SQLgetParea = "SELECT * From students WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]' ";
          $SQLgetPareaResult = mysqli_query($conn,$SQLgetParea);
          $SQLgetPareaRow = mysqli_fetch_array($SQLgetPareaResult,MYSQLI_NUM);
          $getDept = $SQLgetPareaRow[4];

            $sql2 = "SELECT students.*, quiziz.*
                      FROM students 
                      INNER JOIN quiziz 
                      ON students.dept=quiziz.dept 
                      AND students.subject = quiziz.subject 
                      WHERE students.dept = '".$getDept."' 
                        ";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);

                while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2,MYSQLI_NUM)) {
                  echo "
          <a href='quiz.php?subject=".$row2[5]."?dept=".$row2[4]."'>Enter Exam for ".$row2[5]."</a>
          <br><br>";
        }
}
}
```

**quiz.php**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
              if ($_SESSION['usertype'] === "isstudent") {

                $conn->query("SET NAMES utf8"); 
                $conn->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

                $SQLgetParea = "SELECT * From students ";
                $SQLgetPareaResult = mysqli_query($conn,$SQLgetParea);
                $SQLgetPareaRow = mysqli_fetch_array($SQLgetPareaResult,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                $getSub = $SQLgetPareaRow['subject'];

               $sql2 = "SELECT quiziz.*, students.*
                        FROM quiziz 
                        INNER JOIN students 
                        ON quiziz.dept=students.dept 
                        AND quiziz.subject = '".$getSub."' ";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);

                while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

                  echo "
                  <li>".$row2['question']."</li>
                  <li><div class='ruler'></div></li>
                  <li>".$row2['ans1']."</li>
                  <li>".$row2['ans2']."</li>
                  <li>".$row2['ans3']."</li>
                  <li>".$row2['ans4']."</li>
                  ";
                }

              }
            }
```

Comment: Have you checked that your $getSub is not empty? Please, provide the SQL to be executed and the table rows of your table.

Comment: dear @k3rn3llp4n1c i was have some error and its fixed ok i replace this line of code `<a href='quiz.php?subject=".$row2[5]."?dept=".$row2[4]."'>Enter Exam for ".$row2[5]."</a>
          <br><br>"`  with this line       `<a href='quiz.php?subject=".$row2[5]."&dept=".$row2[4]."'>Enter Exam for ".$row2[5]."</a>
          <br><br>`

Comment: but still have to fetch different questions for every user , any idea ?

Comment: This looks like poor design :-(

Comment: Replied on the answer.

Comment: @Strawberry i dont need design , i already have responsive template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch diferent question for every user, create a question table and assign an id for each question you want to show your users.

After that, you just need to create a vector with a random function to fetch those questions by id from your database. Change your column question from quizes to question_id which is a foreign key to your recently created table.

Comment: thats exactly what iam looking for , thanks for advice :) its helps me a lot  
#Accepted